# Programming with Selenium to automate an ARIA:Listbox with c# and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automate a download function from a broker.  I have been able to logon with id and pw, navigate to specific web pages, and select and collect items from the site.  I am stumped, however, on how to select an ARIA:Listbox item in an embedded form.  All the examples I have seen show windows forms listbox or HTML select lists which is not the way this www site is built.

I have been successful with the c# Selenium findelement By.ID for the listbox required, but the last error said it must be scrolled into view.  I'm guessing that the item is not in view because I haven't got the ARIA Listbox click to work to display the list.  I've tried clicking on the dropdown arrow, and on the cell itself but the list doesn't show up.

I need some pointers on what to try next.

Thanks
OK - here's some additional info:
I apologize if this doesn't present right - I'm just learning to use the site...

When I use the program code

```
browser_driver.FindElement(By.Name("OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption")).Click();
```

I get the message

> OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'Element  could not be scrolled into view'

The relevant html follows:

```html
<span id="OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption" role="presentation" onfocusjs="removingDuplicateContentFromMenu();;vg.validation.focus(this)" onchangejs="setWarnings('downloadOption');" onblurjs="vg.validation.blur(this)" class="vg-SelOneMenu" compname="selectOneMenu">
    <div class="vg-SelOneMenuCont vg-SelOneMenuNoWrap vg-SelOneMenuFocusText vg-SelOneMenuHover" id="OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption_cont" aria-owns="menu-OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return false;" class="vg-SelOneMenuTrigger" id="OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption_aTag" role="button" aria-xpanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="menu-OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption" aria-labelledby="downLoadOptionText OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption_text" aria-disabled="false">
```

If I go after "OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption_aTag" with:

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.ID("OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption_aTag")));
browser_driver.FindElement(By.ID("OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption_aTag")).Click();
```

Nothing happens - the popup doesn't occur.

Hope this comes out ok!

Comment: you need to show code example what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

After much research and reading, I figured out that I had to do a two step action in  the program:

```
input_element = browser_driver.FindElement(By.Id("OfxDownloadForm:downloadOption_aTag"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(browser_driver);
    actions.MoveToElement(input_element);
    actions.Perform();
    input_element.Click();
```

I believe the FindElement method just located the element, but didn't reposition the mouse into the document on that element.  MoveToElement method scrolled down the document and brought the element into the view, and then a click on the same element allowed the drop-down listbox to do its processing.   Once I did the find and the move, I was able to select the appropriate dropdown item.